# Take the first n dictionaries of a specific key in a sorted list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I writing a script which calculates the distance in miles between an order's shipping address and each store location for a specific chain of stores. So far, I have created a sorted list of dictionaries (sorted by order_id and then distance). It looks like this:

```
   [
       {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 10,
            "storeID": 1112
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 20,
            "storeID": 1116
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 30,
            "storeID": 1134
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 40,
            "storeID": 1133
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 6,
            "storeID": 1112
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 12,
            "storeID": 1116
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 18,
            "storeID": 1134
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 24,
            "storeID": 1133
        }
    ]
```

From here, I would like to find the two closest stores for each `order_id`, as well as their distances.

What I'd ultimately want to end up with is a list that looks like this:

```
   [
       {
            "order_id": 1,
            "closet_store_distance": 10,
            "closest_store_id": 1112,
            "second_closet_store_distance": 20,
            "second_closest_store_id": 1116
       },
       {
            "order_id": 2,
            "closet_store_distance": 6,
            "closest_store_id": 1112,
            "second_closet_store_distance": 12,
            "second_closest_store_id": 1116
      }
]
```

I am unsure of how to loop through each order_id in this list and select the two closest stores. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I made the assumption that the initial data was in a file called `sample.txt`.

```
import json
from operator import itemgetter

def make_order(stores, id):
   return {
      "order_id": id,
      "closet_store_distance": stores[0][1],
      "closest_store_id": stores[0][0],
      "second_closet_store_distance": stores[1][1],
      "second_closest_store_id": stores[1][0]
   }

def main():
   with open('sample.txt', 'r') as data_file:
      data = json.loads(data_file.read())

   id1 = {}
   id2 = {}
   for i in data:
      if i["order_id"] == 1:
         id1[i["storeID"]] = i["distance"]
      else:
         id2[i["storeID"]] = i["distance"]

   top1 = sorted(id1.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
   top2 = sorted(id2.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

   with open('results.json', 'w') as result_file:
      order1 = make_order(top1, 1)
      order2 = make_order(top2, 2)
      json.dump([order1, order2], result_file, indent=3, separators=(',', ': '))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The resulting file looks like:

```
[
   {
      "second_closest_store_id": 1116,
      "closet_store_distance": 10,
      "closest_store_id": 1112,
      "order_id": 1,
      "second_closet_store_distance": 20
   },
   {
      "second_closest_store_id": 1116,
      "closet_store_distance": 6,
      "closest_store_id": 1112,
      "order_id": 2,
      "second_closet_store_distance": 12
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @navidad. In reality, I have about 30,000 orders that I would need to loop through. So, doing this:

order1 = make_order(top1, 1)
      order2 = make_order(top2, 2)
      json.dump([order1, order2], result_file, indent=3, separators=(',', ': '))

would not really be tenable. What I'm having trouble doing is figuring out how would loop through each order. 

Sorry if I was not being clear before. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @sumojelly did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

A nice readable answer (but using one of my free libraries.):

```
from PLOD import PLOD

order_store_list = [
       {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 10,
            "storeID": 1112
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 20,
            "storeID": 1116
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 30,
            "storeID": 1134
        },
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "distance": 40,
            "storeID": 1133
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 6,
            "storeID": 1112
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 12,
            "storeID": 1116
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 18,
            "storeID": 1134
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "distance": 24,
            "storeID": 1133
        }
]

#
# first, get the order_ids (place in a dictionary to ensure uniqueness)
#
order_id_keys = {}
for entry in order_store_list:
    order_id_keys[entry["order_id"]] = True
#
# next, get the two closest stores per order_id
#
closest_stores = []
for order_id in order_id_keys:
    top_two = PLOD(order_store_list).eq("order_id", order_id).sort("distance").returnList(limit=2)
    closest_stores.append({
        "order_id": order_id,
        "closet_store_distance": top_two[0]["distance"],
        "closest_store_id": top_two[0]["storeID"],
        "second_closet_store_distance": top_two[1]["distance"],
        "second_closest_store_id": top_two[1]["storeID"]
    })
#
# sort by order_id again (if that is important)
#
closest_stores = PLOD(closest_stores).sort("order_id").returnList()
```

This example assumes the production `order_store_list` will fit in memory. If you are using a larger dataset, I strongly recommend using a database and python library for that database.

My PLOD library is free and open source (MIT), but requires Python 2.7. I'm about two weeks away from a Python 3.5 release. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PLOD/0.1.7

Comment: Hey @JohnAD -- thanks for sharing. This looks like a cool library -- especially for someone like me who's used to thinking about things in query form. I'm going to install PLOD and let you know how it goes